# How to identify which is Transverse and conjugate axis of Hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given Equation of Hyperbola as

$$\frac{(x-2y+3)^2}{20}-\frac{(2x+y-1)^2}{\frac{80}{9}}=1$$

we have axes equations as $x-2y+3=0$ and $2x+y-1=0$. But how to identify which is Transverse and which is conjugate?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the hyperbola *cuts only the transverse axis and not the conjugate axis*. So only that axis which gives real points of intersection with hyperbola can be transverse axis.

So $2x+y-1 = 0$ gives real points when solved with hyperbola equation, it is the transverse axis!